# Python - Split string of numeric values with unknown delimiters

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I need to parse the numeric values from a string that is not well formatted. Example:

```
"0    0    .1        .05       .05       0.        0.         .01"
```

or

```
"0,0,.1,.05,.05,0.,0.,.01"
```

As you can see the delimiter can vary from several spaces to commas with no spaces. Also, the numbers may be ints or floats. I would like to split on any number of consecutive spaces, tabs, and commas. I thought I could do this with the `str.split()` function, however I found that it only works with one delimiter argument and will not do commas by default.

Does anyone know a clever way to do this? Possibly with regular expressions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to split on any number of consecutive spaces, tabs, and commas.

You could use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) to split by a regular expression.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '0    0    .1        .05       .05       0.        0.         .01'
>>> re.split(r'[\s,]+', s)

['0', '0', '.1', '.05', '.05', '0.', '0.', '.01']
```

**Note:** The above will split accordingly on whitespace and commas. If you want to split strictly on `<space>`, tabs and commas, you could change the regular expression to `[ \t,]+` ...

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions would work, but you could also just replace every comma with a space and then use regular `split`:

```
s.replace(',', ' ').split()
```

Demo:

```
>>> s = "0    0    .1        .05       .05       0.        0.         .01"
>>> s.replace(',', ' ').split()
['0', '0', '.1', '.05', '.05', '0.', '0.', '.01']

>>> s = "0,0,.1,.05,.05,0.,0.,.01"
>>> s.replace(',', ' ').split()
['0', '0', '.1', '.05', '.05', '0.', '0.', '.01']
```

Comment: Thanks for thinking outside the regular expressions box (+1).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.split`.

```
[ ,]+
```

You can split by this.

```
import re
y="0,0,.1,.05,.05,0.,0.,.01"
print re.split(r"[ ,]+",y)
```

Or

You can use simply use `re.findall`.Here you can have any delimiter.

```
import re
y="0,0,.1,.05,.05,0.,0.,.01"
print re.findall(r"\d*(?:\.\d+)?",y)
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional note on "findall".

Answer (score 0):

You can split with the following regex: `[, ]+`

Example:

```
import re

pattern = r'[,\s]+'

row = "0    0    .1        .05       .05       0.        0.         .01"
re.split(pattern, row)
# > ['0', '0', '.1', '.05', '.05', '0.', '0.', '.01']

row = "0,0,.1,.05,.05,0.,0.,.01"
re.split(pattern, row)
# > ['0', '0', '.1', '.05', '.05', '0.', '0.', '.01']
```